# XSLT 3.0 assertion and exception throwing after iteration

Tags: xslt-3.0

I have XSLT module containing dependent components: iteration, validation and …

> Input example port1.xml

```
<valuationDocument>
  <valuationSet id="val1">
    <assetValuation>
      <objectReference href="tid-1" />
      <quote>
        <value>1000000</value>
        <sensitivitySet>
          <sensitivity name="SEP21">0.707</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="2Y">1.82</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="3Y">2.73</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="4Y">3.68</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="5Y">4.51</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="7Y">3.64</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="10Y">9.06</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="MAR21">0.315</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="15Y">13.59</sensitivity>
        </sensitivitySet>
      </quote>
    </assetValuation>
    <assetValuation>
      <objectReference href="tid-2" />
      <quote>
        <value>1100000</value>
        <sensitivitySet>
          <sensitivity name="SEP21">0.947</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="MAR21">0.502</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="2Y">1.91</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="3Y">2.84</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="4Y">3.72</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="5Y">4.63</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="7Y">3.71</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="10Y">9.15</sensitivity>
          <sensitivity name="15Y">13.64</sensitivity>
        </sensitivitySet>
      </quote>
    </assetValuation>
  </valuationSet>
</valuationDocument>
```

> I am quasi-satisfied with the `iteration` component (incapacitating the `streaming`…). The iteration result is below:

```
<valuationDocument>
   <valuationSet id="val1">
      <assetValuation>
         <objectReference href="tid-1"/>
         <quote>
            <value>1000000</value>
            <BasisPointValue>
               <shiftUp units="100bp" sensitivityName="SEP21" sensitivity="0.707">992,930.00</shiftUp>
               <shiftDown units="100bp" sensitivityName="SEP21" sensitivity="0.707">1,007,070.00</shiftDown>
==========================================================================================
               <shiftUp units="100bp" sensitivityName="15Y" sensitivity="13.59">864,100.00</shiftUp>
               <shiftDown units="100bp" sensitivityName="15Y" sensitivity="13.59">1,135,900.00</shiftDown>
            </BasisPointValue>
            <sensitivitySet>
               <sensitivity name="SEP21">0.707</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="2Y">1.82</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="3Y">2.73</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="4Y">3.68</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="5Y">4.51</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="7Y">3.64</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="10Y">9.06</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="MAR21">0.315</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="15Y">13.59</sensitivity>
            </sensitivitySet>
         </quote>
      </assetValuation>
      <assetValuation>
        <objectReference href="tid-2" />
           <quote>
              <value>1100000</value>
            <BasisPointValue>
               <shiftUp units="100bp" sensitivityName="SEP21" sensitivity="0.947">1,089,583.00</shiftUp>
               <shiftDown units="100bp" sensitivityName="SEP21" sensitivity="0.947">1,110,417.00</shiftDown>
==========================================================================================
               <shiftUp units="100bp" sensitivityName="15Y" sensitivity="13.64">949,960.00</shiftUp>
               <shiftDown units="100bp" sensitivityName="15Y" sensitivity="13.64">1,250,040.00</shiftDown>
            </BasisPointValue>
            <sensitivitySet>
               <sensitivity name="SEP21">0.947</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="MAR21">0.502</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="2Y">1.91</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="3Y">2.84</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="4Y">3.72</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="5Y">4.63</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="7Y">3.71</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="10Y">9.15</sensitivity>
               <sensitivity name="15Y">13.64</sensitivity>
            </sensitivitySet>
         </quote>
      </assetValuation>
   </valuationSet>
</valuationDocument>
```

> I would like to validate the iteration result as soon as it completes. Should any of the validation fail, the exception is reported and the program is terminated. However, the validation **ISN'T** played out after the iteration. (The actual validation is to raise exception through `xsl:try|catch` and terminate if any of the assertion fails)

> The validation logic is to compare three metrics of the `sensitivitySet/sensitivity` with those of iterated & transformed `BasisPointValue/shiftUp|shiftDown/@sensitivity`
> (NOTE: xsl:text is to simulate exception throwing, apparently, the XSLT editor can’t emit the message)

```
    <xsl:variable name="MinE">
        <!-- <xsl:message terminate="yes">Fatal Error: Minimum NPV and BPV sensitivity is different</xsl:message>-->
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Retro: Min NPV and BPV sensitivity</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="MaxE">
        <!--<xsl:message terminate="yes">Fatal Error: Maximum NPV and BPV sensitivity is different</xsl:message>-->
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Retro: Max NPV and BPV sensitivity</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="AvgDownE">
        <!--<xsl:message terminate="yes">Fatal Error: Average NPV and BPV ShiftDown sensitivity is different</xsl:message>-->
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>Retro: Average NPV and BPV ShiftDown</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x9;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:source-document href="port1.xml">
             <xsl:apply-templates select="valuationDocument" mode="val"/>
        </xsl:source-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sensitivitySet" mode="val">

<!--  ITERATION -->     
    ==========================================
        <!--        <xsl:apply-imports/>-->
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="parent::quote" mode="validation"/>
    </xsl:template>
  
<!--  VALIDATION -->
    <xsl:template match="quote" mode="validation" expand-text="yes">
        <Assertion>
             <xsl:variable name="m" as="map(*)">
                <xsl:map>
                   <xsl:map-entry key="'min-npv'" select="min(outermost(descendant::sensitivity)/number())"/>
                   <xsl:map-entry key="'max-npv'" select="max(outermost(descendant::sensitivity)/number())"/>
                   <xsl:map-entry key="'min-bpv'" select="min(outermost(descendant::BasisPointValue//@sensitivity)/number())"/>
                   <xsl:map-entry key="'max-bpv'" select="max(outermost(descendant::BasisPointValue//@sensitivity)/number())"/>
                   <xsl:map-entry key="'avg-npv'" select="avg(outermost(descendant::sensitivity)/number())"/>
                   <xsl:map-entry key="'avg-bpv-down'" select="avg(outermost(descendant::BasisPointValue/shiftDown/@sensitivity)/number())"/>
                 </xsl:map>
              </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="deep-equal($m('min-npv'), $m('min-bpv'))">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$MinE"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="deep-equal($m('max-npv'), $m('max-bpv'))">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$MaxE"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="deep-equal($m('avg-npv'), $m('avg-bpv-down'))">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$AvgDownE"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="'Validation Succeeds!'"/></xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
        </Assertion> 
    </xsl:template>
```

> What is the XSLT3.0 solution of validation after the iteration?

Comment: I haven't understood what you are trying to do in the samples. The text talks about assertions and validation, does assertions refer to the `xsl:assert` https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#assertions element and "validation" to schema-aware XSLT 2/3 validating nodes against XSD schema types?

Comment: A tenable assertion: calculate the min, max and avg of iterating `BasisPointValue` sensitivity; calculate the min, max and avg of the in-situ `quote` sensitivity (using XPath); proceed a point-in-time validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, this is a standard multi-phase transformation. You can either use two separate stylesheets, chained together using some external API (e.g. shell script, Ant/gradle, XProc, Java application) or you can put both phases in the same stylesheet using the logic

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="phase-1"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$temp" mode="phase-2"/>
```